# Getting attachment in vb.net from gmail

Tags: gmail, email-attachments, gmail-api

Here's my code to retrieve attachment from Gmail message

```
Dim attachPart As MessagePartBody = myGMailService.Users.Messages.Attachments.Get(ProfileUsager.GoogleAccountUserName, ID, attachmentID).Execute()

Dim fileByteArray() As Byte = Convert.FromBase64String(attachPart.Data())
```

My problem is `Convert.FromBase64String`, this return:

> L'entrée n'est pas une chaîne Base 64 valide, car elle contient un caractère non-Base 64, plus de deux caractères de remplissage ou un caractère non conforme parmi les caractères de remplissage.

How I can resolve this? This code is a code block I found on Google API doc.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Please provide the details of the issue.. Its hard to understand from the description.